# Capturing form input in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Right now I have my form set up with a generic button. Would it be easier to use a submit?
I'm trying to capture the user input and then pass it on as part of a URL. Using .find has been getting me an array of something else.

```
div class="username-input form-horizontal">
  <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
  <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" value="Username" id="inputUsername">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button class="signup-button col-sm-1 control-label"> Sign in  </button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".signup-button").click(function() {
        var usernameInput = $('form').find('input[type=text]')
        console.log(usernameInput)
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe you want to use .val instead of .find http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing the element not the value. Use `val` for it

```
var usernameInput = $('form').find('input[type=text]').val(); // now you get input
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have input field ID & it should be unique so you can use ID as selector also.

```
var name = $("#inputUsername").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access value. This is the way you can access value of input text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".signup-button").click(function() {
       var usernameInput = $('#inputUsername').val();
        console.log(usernameInput);
    });
});
```